# Missing gridlines for spline with single repeating value

Tags: highcharts

I'm plotting a spline for a generated series. When the series contains the same repeating value (x axis Datetime increasing, Y axis same int value), the gridlines disappear and the only way I can see the value is to hover over the point.

Note: The min and max are not explicitly set, as they are determined by the data at run-time.

Is there a way to force the grid to appear? I'm guessing the min and max are getting set to the value on the chart, so is there someway for it to show min as val - offset and max as val + offset at runtime perhaps?

Comment: So you have the same points (x/y) in single serie, or a few series with the same points ? is it possible to recreate in jsfiddle?

Comment: I have multiple points in the same series, with a different datetime in x and the same value in y. I'll work on creating a fiddle to give an example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KPH5v/ This shows an example. If I set min = 0, then I see grid lines. However ,in my data, I don't know what the min and max values will be, so it would be best to have them as +- 10-20% of the value.

Comment: You can set min/max values or tickInterval.